# Sitecore hide publish button from users on select content items

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Is it possible to hide the publish button from user roles on select content items?

For example if I have two content folders "A" and "B" and User role "1"

I want user "1" to be able to add content to both folders but only publish content in folder "B" as A needs to be reviewed by an admin.

I have a workflow implemented to prevent publishing but the publish button remains.

I am working with Sitecore version 6.6

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can use workflow as autoPublish once the item has been approved. By changing the publish permission, you can hide publish button.

**For Content Editor**

1. Access with admin account and move to Core DB in Desktop Mode
2. Select the role or User in User Manager
3. Click "Security Editor"
4. Move "Application -> Content Editor -> Menue -> Publish"
   [image]
5. Or, you can remove the "Publish" button by moving "Applications -> Content Editor -> Ribbons -> Publish -> Publish"

[image]

6. Select "X" to hide "Publish" options you want in Read field

**For Page Editor**

1. Access with admin account and move to Core DB in Desktop Mode
2. Select the role or User in User Manager
3. Click "Security Editor"
4. Move "Applications -> WebEdit -> Ribbons -> WebEdit -> Page Editor -> Publish"
   [image]
5. Select "X" to hide "Publish" options you want in Read field